How to approach: csv objects specified on command line or in a file
I would like to accept 2d points provided on the command line or read from a file. Example command line positional parameter input:
(   4,-1),(0,  0)                   , (3,3)

example CSV file
4, -1
                     0,0

3             ,3

I.e. "comma outside braces" and "newline" are the two possible separators. I can see 3 roads ahead:

re(not sure if even possible if number of provided points is unknown)
some magic from python's legendary "batteries"(module csv seems a bit overengineered for such a simple use case, is that true?)
the C way - feed the string to a state machine
entirely separate handling for the two formats
get rid of spaces, perhaps of '\n'(see comments).

It's mostly a conceptual question so any criticism a la "this is a dumb question" or "this is an AB question" is welcome more than code.

It is not clear how your input horizontal whitespace is being translated to the example output horizontal whitespacing. Why does the input (0,  0)                   , get translated to '                     0,0'? Why , (3,3) => 3             ,3?

@dawg they are 2 different representations of the same set of 2D points. One from stdin, one from CSV. With some random whitespace thrown in.

So the second is not example output from interpreting the first, it is another example of input?

@dawg the second is expected to produce identical output(the values assigned to variables) as the first. Those are the "wrongest" representations I accept - mismatched braces, missed numbers, letters etc. are allowed to just raise BaseException('You are wrong.')

I don't understand why you can't get rid of spaces? even programmatically, smth like strip() ?

Do you really mean the command line, not stdin? As in python script.py '(   4,-1),(0,  0)                   , (3,3)'?

As long as you don't allow nested braces, you can easily parse this with re.findall(r'\(.*?\)')

@Barmar yeah, this sounds like the magical bullet I'm looking for. But it's a bit late, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks a ton! My efficiency constraint is 64*64 points parsed within 10ms on an raspberry B but I suspect any solution would surpass that by orders of magnitude.

Probably easiest with a regex.
You first need to tighten the definition of your grammar. Are the pairs in braces only allowed in stdin? Can you have a mixture?
Here is method for the brace pairs:
import re 

command_line="(   4,-1),(0,  0)                   , (3,3)"

int_pairs1=[]
for pp in re.split(r'(?<=\))[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?=\()', command_line):
    if ',' in pp:
        int_pairs1.append(list(
            map(int, re.sub(r'\(\s*|\s*\)', "", pp).split(',',1) ) ) )

And another for the file example:
file_in='''\
4, -1
                     0,0

3             ,3
'''

int_pairs2=[]
for  pp in (l.strip() for l in file_in.splitlines()):
    if pp.strip() and ',' in pp:
        int_pairs2.append(list(map(int, pp.split(',',1) ) ) )

And they produce the same output with their respective inputs:
>>> int_pairs1==int_pairs2
True

The exception is raised by the attempt to convert the constituent parts to an int.

Thanks for solving my "homework"! It's too late now so I'll give it a go tomorrow. Awkward situation is this is multiplayer game map initialization but python has the name reserved for something more useful(please no lectures or scope and shadowing).

Since the input from the command line is a valid representation of a tuple of tuple literals, you can simply parse it with ast.literal_eval:
import ast

print(ast.literal_eval('(   4,-1),(0,  0)                   , (3,3)'))

This outputs:
((4, -1), (0, 0), (3, 3))

Similarly, you can parse each non-blank line of the CSV file as a tuple:
import ast
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO('''\
4, -1
                     0,0

3             ,3
''')
print(tuple(map(ast.literal_eval, filter(str.strip, file))))

This outputs:
((4, -1), (0, 0), (3, 3))

Demo here
